# Error: "Username value length exceeds 20 characters" when calling Sabre CarAvailability in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman, sabre

I am trying to make a POST request to the [Sabre CarAvailability API](https://beta.developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/ground/search/car_availability/reference-documentation) with Postman. When I make the request I get back the following error: **Username value length exceeds 20 characters**.

- I obtained a bearer token and added it to the authorization section of my request
- I added the `carAvailabilityRequest` object as raw data, in the body section of the request.
- I tried changing the values of this object, but so far without luck. I know I am doing something wrong but I have no idea what.

Here is the carAvailabilityRequest object I passed:

```
{
  "OTA_VehAvailRateRQ": 
  {
    "TimeStamp": "string",
    "Version": "string",
    "ReturnHostCommand": true,
    "VehAvailRQCore": 
    {
      "RPH": 0,
      "QueryType": "Quote", 
      "VehRentalCore": 
      {
        "PickUpDateTime": "03-31T09:00",
        "ReturnDateTime": "04-05T11:00",
        "PickUpLocation": 
        {
          "LocationCode": "DFW",
          "CityLocation": "string"
        },
        "ReturnLocation": 
        {
          "LocationCode": "DFW"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The request does not get through and I get the following error message:

```
{
    "Fault": {
        "faultcode": "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client.EbXmlFieldTooLong",
        "faultstring": "Username value length exceeds 20 characters",
        "detail": {
            "StackTrace": [
                "com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.InvalidEbXMLException: errors.xml.USG_EBXML_FIELD_TOO_LONG"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v2.4.1/shop/cars"
        },
        {
            "rel": "linkTemplate",
            "href": "https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/<version>/shop/cars"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me solve this issue - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the message "Username value length exceeds 20 characters" I would expect that something is wrong with your authentification.

When following the link in your error response `https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v2.4.1/shop/cars` it says again that something is wrong with your authentification/the authentification data is missing:

[image: Error response]

It seems that something is not configured correctly with your authentification/bearer token or are you maybe sending to a wrong endpoint?

Something else you could try is setting the `Content-Type` of your request body to `application/json` because the [API documentation](https://beta.developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/ground/search/car_availability/reference-documentation#/default/carAvailability) you provided seems to define it this way.

You can do this in Postman in the Headers tab of your request:

[image: Postman Headers tab]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Content-Type was already set to application/json.
I have a bearer token which is 1600 characters long. If I trim it to 20 characters I get the "missing credentials" error. If I leave it as is, I get the "Username value length exceeds 20 characters" error. I will inspect everything in postman again, to see what I learn.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out myself with the same error message using the version v2.4.1

If you make the same request to a previous version you will get an appropiate answer.
Use v2.4.0
https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v2.4.0/shop/cars

HTH
Pablo.